# Bash: Can't store command output into a variable when executing commands in SSH

Tags: bash

My bash script is

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh <HOST_IP> << EOF
echo "here"
output=$(echo "here")
echo $output
EOF
```

When I ran it, I got:

```
here
```

meaning that the `$output` variable was empty. How can this be? I SSHed into the host manually and ran the same commands, and was able to get `"here"` in `$output`.

Comment: the shell is expanding your `$...` in the heredoc before `ssh` executes it. You should use a **quoted** heredoc `ssh ... <<'EOF'`

Comment: Your output almost certainly contained a blank line underneath `here`.